# How do I fix leaking SSLSessionImpl in Glassfish?

Tags: memory-leaks, glassfish

So the basics are I have Glassfish 2.1 and Java 1.6.0_15 and it will work for a few days but it eats up all the memory it can, seemingly no matter how high the max memory is set to.  It's a 32-bit jvm with the max memory now at 4GB and it uses it all up quickly then thrashes with the garbage collector bringing throughput to a crawl.  So after a few tries I got a 3GB heap dump and opened it with YourKit.

The usage on this server is a swing client doing a few RMI calls and some REST https calls, plus a php web site calling a lot of REST https services.

It shows:

```
Name                                          Objects    Shallow Size     Retained Size
java.lang.Class                               22,422     1,435,872        1,680,800,240
java.lang.ref.Finalizer                       3,086,366  197,527,424      1,628,846,552
com.sun.net.sll.internal.ssl.SSLSessionImpl   3,082,887  443,935,728      1,430,892,816
byte[]                                        7,901,167  666,548,672      666,548,672
```

...and so on.  Gee, where did the memory go?  Oh, 3 million SSLSessionImpl instances, that's all.

It seems like all the https calls are causing these SSLSessionImpl objects to accumulate, but then they are never GC'ed.  Looking at them in YourKit, the finalizer is the GC root.  Poking around the web this looks very much like http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5266266 and https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug;jsessionid=80df6098575e8599df9ba5c9edc1?bug_id=6386530

Where do I go next?  How do I get to the bottom of this?

Comment: So are you saying this is an issue you've seen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be fixed now with an upgrade to the latest JVM.  [1.6.0_18](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/webnotes/6u18.html) fixes [bug 4918870](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4918870) which is related to this.  Prior to upgrading the JVM, I had several heap dumps with 100,000-4,000,000 SSLSessionImpl, now there are usually less than 5000 instances.